# How to populate a composite list from a map with arrays using Dozer

Tags: java, arraylist, dictionary, dozer

I have a map containing three arrays.

For example:

```
id[1,2,3]
name["a","b","c"]
type["x1","y2","z3"]
```

And I also have a "MyObject" object containing three properties:

```
Long myId;
String myName;
Long myType;
```

and a "MyObjectList" object one of the properties of which contains a list (myList) with the following objects:

```
List<MyObject> myList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
```

In other words, in my example, the list has to include three MyObject objects:

```
{myId=1;name="a";type="x1"}
{myId=2;name="b";type="x2"}
{myId=3;name="c";type="x3"}
```

How can I use Dozer to populate the given list?

Best regards,
Sergey

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: the problem is not solved yet... =(